# Why are some checkboxes in Software Updater disabled?

Tags: apt, software-updater

In Ubuntu 13.04, the *Software Updater* shows some apps as having updates, but they're non-selectable:

[image]

It's not clear why they're greyed out.

On the command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnuplot-nox gnuplot-x11 nvidia-current
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Note too that running `apt-get dist-upgrade` does not cause them to be installed either, as it sometimes does with packages that are kept back. Here's the output:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnuplot-nox gnuplot-x11 nvidia-current
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I took @quidage's suggestion, which gives the following. However subsequent upgrades show the same message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f`? Maybe you have broken dependencies.

Comment: @quidage, I tried your suggestion but it had no effect. I've edited my question with the output I observed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` wouldn't solve my issue, but I obtained the package names `libodbc1` and `wine-stable` under `The following packages have been kept back`:

```
xb@dnxb:~$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1 wine-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Then simply manually `apt install` that particular package to see the relevant error details:

```
xb@dnxb:~$ sudo apt-get install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.1~bionic)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.1~bionic) but 4.0.3~bionic is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
xb@dnxb:~$ sudo apt-get install libodbc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  msodbcsql17 unixodbc-bin
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libodbc1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libodbc1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 511 kB of archives.
After this operation, 657 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 2):

`The following packages have been kept back:` normally means you have **upgrades** and not **updates** of packages.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

will fix this. It will  show the following messages...

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
```

and

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
```

Comment: Thanks, but `dist-upgrade` doesn't help as I mentioned in an edit to the question (possibly around the time you answered.) I'll include the output in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the state of your package:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "name of your package"
```

if it shows the status `hold` the checkbox in the Software Updater window can not be checked.

To remove the `hold` run

```
sudo apt-mark unhold "name of your package"
```

Comment: The status returned by `dpkg` for all _held back_ packages is `install` on my machine. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this also:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "gnuplot-nox"
gnuplot-nox                 install
```

What I did is to run

```
$ sudo aptitude update
$ sudo aptitude upgrade
```

and aptitude decided to uninstall gnuplot-nox. After that, I had to install gnuplot package. I don't know what's going on, tough.

Comment: Were they previously marked as held back? I didn't try using `aptitude` directly. Next time I see this issue, I'll try that too.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation could also be [PhasedUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates):

> Once an update is released to -updates, the update is then phased so that the update is gradually made available to expanding subsets of Ubuntu users. This process allows us to automatically monitor for regressions and halt the update process if any are found.